# Avoid too much if statements

Tags: c#

my code is something like this:

```
if (Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Contains(number) { return 56 }

else if (Enumerable.Range(11, 24).Contains(number) { return 55 }

Other else if statements
```

And this stataments till returning 35!!! How to improve this? I tried using a for loop but without success

Comment: Can you describe in plain English what your code is supposed to do? You have shown us a small part of your solution, but if we don't know what the problem is that your code tries to solve, we won't be able to suggest better alternative solutions.

Comment: The user input a number and then I check if this number is within a specific range that goes from 1 to 256. If the number is in the first range (1, 10) I return a result (56). If the number is in the second range (10, 20) I return 55 etc from arriving till the last result that can be 35

Comment: This is inconsistent with your sample code.

Comment: Maybe 57 - ((number + 9) / 10)?

Comment: @DavidLibido That formula probably won't work, as it would return the same value for 24 and 27 which doesn't seem to be consistent with the requirement.

Comment: That depends on which requirement is actually the correct one.

Comment: Before you post at [codereview.se], make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. you must show _real_, not example, code, and question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Comment: Sorry for the not being ao clear. The best solution for my purpose is the last one, which doesn't need an error handling. Thank you very much guys.

Answer (score 3):

You could shorten it a little bit:

```
if (number < 1) throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(number));

if (number < 11) return 56;
if (number < 25) return 55;
if (number < ??) return ??;
```

... and so on.

For around a dozen numbers, my personal subjective opinion is that it's more readable than defined ranges and a loop. Obviously, if you get your ranges from another source and they aren't hardcoded, that would not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a list of tuples containing the bounds and replacement value:

```
private int GetValueFromRange(int input)
{
    var ranges = new 
    {
        (LowerBound: 1, UpperBound: 10, Value: 56),
        (11, 20, 55),
        (21, 30, 54),
        // ...
    };

    foreach (var range in ranges)
    {
        if (range.LowerBound <= input && range.UpperBound >= input)
        {
            return range.Value;
        }
    }
    
    return -1;
}
```

But this isn't really more readable code or anything, and needs error handling added. If the range is continuous you could omit the lower bound.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a collection with limits and the expected output and then just find the correct tuple in that collection.

```
var limits = new List<(int, int, int)> {
    (11, 20, 1),  //lower limit, upper limit, return value
    (21, 30, 2),
    (31, 40, 3)
};
    
var number = 23;
var l = limits.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Item1 <= number && x.Item2 >= number);
    
Console.WriteLine(l.Item3);
```

If no valid range is found, the default return value will be `0`